Expo Development Build: Updated Permission Is Not Reflected Android Manifest
I upgraded my Expo SDK to v51 and received the following error:
[Error: Call to function 'ExpoLocation.startLocationUpdatesAsync' has been rejected.

→ Caused by: Couldn't start the foreground service. Foreground service permissions were not found in the manifest]

As the error states, this is caused by ExpoLocation. I ask the user for permission and even if everything is allowed as necessary the error prevails.
App.json
"android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/app-icon512.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION",
        "FOREGROUND_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "CAMERA",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ],
    },

This happens when I run the app in both Expo Go and as Expo Development Build.
Any ideas on how to update the manifest?
Thank you!
I tried to run the app in Expo Go as well as an Expo Dev Build.

The solution was fairly easy.
First, I had to add into app.json
    "plugins": [
  [
    "expo-location",
    {
      "isAndroidBackgroundLocationEnabled": true,
      "isAndroidForegroundServiceEnabled": true
    }
  ],

And since afaik changes into app.json are part of native code, you need to rebuild your development build in order to register the changes.
In my case I did
eas build --platform android --profile development

